# How to change images/text in webpage after deploying the webapp

Tags: java, jquery, html, image, jsp

I have a image placed in a jsp. I have the image kid.jpg downloaded and kept in /resources/images folder. The below is the code snippet.

```
<li style="background-image: url('resources/images/kid.jpg');">
```

Now my web app is up and running. How to give end user to change that image/ upload a different image in that place. The same with the text in a div. 
I am not getting the data from database and adding to the div dynamically.

Is database communication only way in such cases or any other way? I see many web sites contents are changing day by day. Are they modifying the webpages and replacing the existing files/ are they getting the data from database? 
Please suggest how to achieve such scenarios.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If There is no database on server and  you want to allow all users ( unregistered ) to change a specific image, then what you can do is :-  store the image file name in cookie, and on server check every time for that cookie, and if does not exists and render the same output with default image, other wise use that cookie's file_name image , and then on client side you can provide a facality to users to select images from particulers images that reside on server, and when user select some image so save that file name in cookie :) , Sorry for spelling mistakes,  It's just a overview of solution of your problem :)